# How to give curved shape to textview in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi everyone I am totally new in Android. I want to design a textview as I uploaded in picture. Is this possible to give shape to textview like this?? If it is possible please help me. Thanks in Advance.[image]

Comment: yes. just use background image

Comment: i suggest you to use 9 patch image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[image: ss[1]]
I created simple custom view about this article. You will use setText(String arg) method not setText(CharSquence text).

```
public class CurvedTextView extends TextView {

    private Context mContext;
    private int width, height;
    private Paint textPaint, drawPaint;
    private Path mPath;
    private String mText = null;


    public CurvedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public CurvedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public CurvedTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context){
        mContext = context;
        width = height = -1;
        textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        textPaint.setTextSize(18.0f);
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        drawPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        drawPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                width = getWidth();
                height = getHeight();
                mPath = new Path();
                mPath.moveTo(getLeft(), getTop());
                mPath.lineTo(getLeft(), getTop());
                mPath.quadTo(height / 2, height / 2, getLeft(), height);
                mPath.lineTo(width, height);
                mPath.lineTo(width, 0);
                mPath.lineTo(0, 0);
                mPath.close();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        mText = text;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, drawPaint);
        if(mText != null){
            canvas.drawText(mText, height/2, height/2, textPaint);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It is possible but carefully about edittext cursor position.

Comment: Thanks buddy!! I have one more query If you don't mind. Can we set padding/margin by the percentage of screen for textview ?

Comment: You will use declare stylable. This article give you more info. http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Comment: I am trying to show text inside the textview but it is not shwoing at all. I have tried to set android:textColor also. plz help me!!@nurisezgin

Comment: Could you send all code to me? "nurisezgin.sezgin@gmail.com"

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom background image. Create custom_image.xml in drawable folder and in mainActivity.xml use it as a background parameter.like this:

android:background="@drawable/custom_image"

Comment: Thanks! I am able to give round shape to it but not curved so please help me to get it.

Comment: You can create a curved image using nine patch image.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: Save this in drawable folder as curved_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >         
   <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="@color/common_border_color" />

   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

   <padding
           android:left="1dp"
           android:right="1dp"
           android:top="1dp" />

   <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

step-2:

set the background property of your text view as follows

```
android:background="@drawable/curved_view"
```

Comment: Thanks to answer , I have tried it but didn't get anything. It is displaying just a simple box.